# Selecting common elements in dataframes Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 DFs, and I want to find all cells with common directions (i.e. always positive or always negative, across DFs):

```
test=pd.DataFrame([[0,1,0,3],
                   [-1,3,0,2],
                   [2,1.5,-3,1]],
                  columns=['a','b','c','d']
                   )
test2=pd.DataFrame([[1,1,0,2],
                   [1,-3,0,1],
                   [2,1.5,-2,1]],
                  columns=['a','b','c','d']
                   )
test3=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,0,2],
                   [1,-2,0,1],
                   [2,1.5,-2,1]],
                  columns=['a','b','c','d']
                   )
```

The outcome should be the 3 dataframes, where elements that are not consistent show NAs. For instance, for `test1` it would be:

```
test=pd.DataFrame([[NA,1,NA,3],
                   [NA,NA,NA,2],
                   [2,1.5,-3,1]],
                  columns=['a','b','c','d']
                   )
```

Note that 0 is not considered (i.e., leads to NA). 
I can do this cell by cell, but I'm wondering if this is possible to do in the 
entire dataframes at once?

I was trying to do `((test>0)&(test1>0)&(test2>0))` and this works, but I cannot merge this with the negatives.

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different approach - you could stack the underlying arrays together, use `np.sign`, then sum and reduce over the added dimension to generate a mask for `df.where`.

```
In [58]: m, n = test.shape

In [59]: signs = np.sign(np.dstack((test, test2, test3)))

In [60]: mask = np.abs(np.sum(signs, -1)) == m

In [61]: test.where(mask)
Out[61]: 
     a    b    c  d
0  NaN  1.0  NaN  3
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  2
2  2.0  1.5 -3.0  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.sign` and addition with a equality test then `where` to do this:

```
 test.where(np.sign(test).add(np.sign(test2)).add(np.sign(test3)).abs() == 3)
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c  d
0  NaN  1.0  NaN  3
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  2
2  2.0  1.5 -3.0  1
```